# Log Analytics alert rule at specific time

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I have a DataFactory with diagnostic setting activate and sending logs to a Log Analytics Workspace.

I want to create an alert that fires only once if an event trigger hasn't run after 9AM.

I think some query like this:

```
let StartTime =startofday(now());
let EndTime =now();
let CheckHour = 9;
ADFTriggerRun
| where ResourceId contains toupper("DataFactory_Name")
| where TriggerName == "Trigger_Name"
| where TimeGenerated > StartTime and TimeGenerated < EndTime
| extend Hour = datetime_part("hour", TimeGenerated)
| where Hour < CheckHour
```

But I see some problems if I set the following settings to the alert:

- Number of results less than 0
- Period = 30 minutes
- Frequency = 30 minutes

(If the trigger runs correctly) The alert will fire 18 times before 9AM.

(If the trigger doesn't run) The alert will fire 48 times in a day.

Is there some query to avoid this? Maybe with some *if* condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such solution to directly solve this issue.

I suggest you can set up 2 alerts:

**Alert 1:** To send alert if the trigger doesn't run all the day. You can use your query in your question, just set `Period = 1440 minutes`, `Frequency = 1440 minutes`, `Number of results less than 0`. Then it will only send one alert email if the trigger doesn't run at all.

**Alert 2:** Use the query below by adding [iff() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ifffunction):

```
let StartTime =startofday(now());
let EndTime =now();
let CheckHour = 9;
ADFTriggerRun
| where ResourceId contains toupper("DataFactory_Name")
| where TriggerName == "trigger1"
| where TimeGenerated > StartTime and TimeGenerated < EndTime
| extend Hour = datetime_part("hour", TimeGenerated)
| extend isFailed = iff(Hour < CheckHour, "Success","Failed")
| where isFailed == "Failed"
```

Then set `Period = 30 minutes`, `Frequency = 30 minutes`, `Number of results Equal to 1`. By using this query / setting, you at most receive 2 email alerts if the triggers runs after 9AM(For example, if the trigger runs at 10:07AM, and the alert scans at 10:20AM / 10:50AM, only at these 2 times, it will send alerts; if the trigger runs before 9AM, no alerts will be sent).

Comment: Thanks @ivan-yang I'll try Alert 2.
I don't like Alert 1 because I have to create the alert at 9AM to see the alert fired at 9AM. If for example I modify the severity of the alert at 11AM I'll recive the alert at 11AM

Comment: Hi @ivan-yang  I studied your solution Alert 2, but it won't alert me if the trigger doesn't run, for example if the file that runs the trigger doesn't arrive one day.

Comment: @Ed_Ru, I already mentioned it in the answer. You have to set up both of the 2 alerts. Alert 2 does not work if the trigger does not run one day, so you need to create another alert like alert 1 to do that thing. Otherwise, there're no other ways simple for your purpose.

Comment: @Ed_Ru set up 2 alerts should be the only way to do that as far as I know. If the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.